# Reskit POST operation not working proper (error 1016)

Tags: ios, restkit, content-type, tastypie

I'm trying to bind RestKit with a REST API created by Django-Tastypie.
`GET` operations work well but `POST` operations have weird behaviors : a row is created on database but all fields are empty.

I have RestKit on version `0.20.3-dev`

Here's my code (directly copied from [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object)) :

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"pseudo", @"email", @"password"]];
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
RKResponseDescriptor *userDescriptor2 = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping pathPattern:@"/user" keyPath:@"objects" statusCodes:statusCodes];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"pseudo", @"email", @"password"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"objects"];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000"]];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:userDescriptor2];

// Tastypie error without this line
manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

// This line changes nothing
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

User *user = [User new];
user.pseudo = @"test";
user.email = @"test@gmail.com";
user.password = @"test";

[manager postObject:user path:@"/api/v1/user/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

And this are errors i get :

```
2013-06-29 02:18:21.882 test_restkit[40395:c07] I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized... 2013-06-29 02:18:21.930 test_restkit[40395:c07] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/post/' 2013-06-29 02:18:21.930 test_restkit[40395:c07] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/' 2013-06-29 02:18:21.965 test_restkit[40395:4c03] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json" )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xa8437b0 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json" )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x95866b0>} 2013-06-29 02:18:21.966 test_restkit[40395:4c03] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:243 POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/' (201 Created / 0 objects) [request=0.0304s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0402s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json" )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xa8437b0 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json" )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x95866b0>} 2013-06-29 02:18:22.023 test_restkit[40395:1703] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/post/' (200 OK / 4 objects) [request=0.0816s mapping=0.0109s total=0.1023s]
```

Someone already faced this kind of issue ?

Thx for your help.

**EDIT :**

Here's much logs with trace logging enable :

```
2013-06-29 13:03:28.554 test_restkit[42627:c07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2013-06-29 13:03:28.562 test_restkit[42627:c07] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:178 POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "test_restkit/1.0 (iPad Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/1.00)";
}
request.body={"objects":{"password":"test","pseudo":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

By editing this line :

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"objects"];
```

by

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:nil];
```

A row is created and field are correctly populated. But i still getting content-type error

Comment: What is the server expecting? Also, the server should respond with JSON, but its actually sending text (probably an error message but that isn't shown). Turn on trace logging and add the failure blocks with logging.

Comment: I edited my post with trace logging. I also add failure blocks with logging but error is the same as in my post

Comment: The aim is to get the error text sent back by the server where it should tell you what's wrong. Until you know that you can't know what to fix.

Comment: Actually it seems that all's good on server side : `[29/Jun/2013 07:08:48] "POST /api/v1/user/ HTTP/1.1" 201 0`

Comment: So why does it not respond with JSON?

Comment: Which information you need ? I give you all i have atm :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is just that you're telling RestKit to expect to receive JSON, but the server isn't sending JSON (or at least not setting the correct header). The best way to resolve the issue is to change the headers on the server response such that it returns JSON. Alternatively, tell RestKit not to expect to receive JSON.

Comment: Okay my bad, I misunderstood your last comments ... As you pointed it, my server wasn't responding in JSON but in HTML. I needed to add `always_return_data = True` on Tastypie and modify my RKResponseDescriptor accordingly. Thx for your help @Wain.

Comment: and how do i tell restkit not to expect to receive JSON? i dont' have control over the api return headers.. i also noticed that changing the `RKObjectManager` `requestSerializationMIMEType` doesn't make any difference.. i'm looking at hte wrong place?

Comment: I even tried [setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Network/RKObjectManager.h?source=c) to `@"text/html"` but no luck.. it's weird b/c in my other projects this worked when i used that with AFNetworking (ie without the restkit stuff)